# Is the Veracode Update and Scan task available in the ADO Pipeline marketplace?

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline, veracode

I need to use the 'Veracode Update and Scan' task inside an ADO pipeline. Unfortunately the task is not available in the Maketplace. Is the task public or I need to contact the Veracode support or more guidance?

I did try finding if the task is deprecated by Microsoft or not but couldn't find anything.
Also there is nothing related to Veracode in the Microsoft documentation about ADO tasks:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/?view=azure-pipelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Veracode.veracode-vsts-build-extension